# when i write something in div and add more content all div child effected what should i do

Tags: html, css

Here is a link for my issue have a look and give me a suggestionhttp://jsfiddle.net/naman750/ansnebyb/1/ `

Comment: You may have to explain more. Just a link to jsfiddle wouldn't help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you chose to use block-inline you must set vertical-align. So, add to first_box a

> vertical-align: top